# How to keep the submenu open in the page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, web-applications

I want to keep the submenu open at the page load itself. How can I make it possible?

Here is the jquery:

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clicking on the first `a` element "opens" the "submenu" you can trigger the `click` event on DOM ready event:

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function() {
    // ...
}).first().click();
```

If you want to select a different `a` element you can use the `.eq()` method:

```
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function() {
    // ...
}).eq(2).click(); // trigger the click event on the third `a` element in the collection
```

Without using `.first()` or `.eq()` method the event will be triggered for all the elements in the set. You could also use the `.trigger('click')` or `.triggerHandler('click')` method.